# FFMPEG with Rails 4.2 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to convert an uploaded wav file in a mp3.

My code works in development mode but not in production and I can't find where the error is. As far as I can tell, I think it's a path problem with the tmp file. FFMPEG works in production (Digital Ocean) when I run a command on the terminal.

My mp3 job:

```
    class Mp3UploadJob < Struct.new(:audiofile_id)

      def perform
        path = audiofile.wav_file.url.to_s
        mp3_file = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "uploads", "#{audiofile.filename}.mp3")
        %x[ffmpeg -i "#{path}" -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -metadata title="#{audiofile.title}" -metadata artist="#{audiofile.mp3_artist_name}" -metadata album="#{audiofile.mp3_album}" -metadata date="#{audiofile.release_date}" -metadata genre="#{audiofile.genre}" "#{mp3_file}"]
        audiofile.mp3_file = open(mp3_file)
        audiofile.save!
        File.delete(mp3_file)
      end

    end
```

Note: the wav file comes from a dropbox chooser box.

My wav job (ran before the mp3 job):

```
    class WavUploadJob < Struct.new(:audiofile_id)

      def perform
        audiofile.remote_wav_file_url = audiofile.dropbox_wav
        audiofile.save!
      end
    end
```

Comment: If you're using `paperclip` to attach files to your model, you could just use a processor - https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-wav-mp3

Comment: I'm using carrier wave which has something equivalent than paperclip. Unfortunately it doesn't work with remote urls.